# How can I merge and maintain the row order of one input?

Tags: r, sorting, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame that relates bottle numbers to their volumes (`key` in the example below).  I want to write a function that will take any list of bottle numbers (`samp`) and return a list of the bottle volumes **while maintaining the bottle number order in `samp`**.

The function below correctly matches the bottle numbers and volumes but sorts the output by ascending bottle number.

How can I maintain the order of `samp` with `merge`?  Setting `sort=FALSE` results in an "unspecified order".

**Example**

```
samp <- c(9, 1, 4, 1)
num <- 1:10
vol <- sample(50:100, 10)
key <- data.frame(num, vol)
matchFun <- function(samp, key)
  {
    out <- merge(as.data.frame(samp), key, by.x="samp", by.y="num")
    return(out$vol)
  }
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to maintain the original order of `samp` for some reason though...

Comment: Well crap, I apologize.  `sort=FALSE` returns the rows in an "unspecified order".  Looks like I need to RTFM. ;-)  Bring on the "great comment" up-votes.  I like my crow well-done.

Comment: Thanks for the edits!  That is a much clearer description of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `match` and subsetting `key` by the result:

```
bottles <- key[match(samp, key$num),]
# rownames are odd because they must be unique, clean them up
rownames(bottles) <- seq(NROW(bottles))
```

Comment: Joshua, shouldn't it be `match(key$num, samp)` instead? Because according to `?match` the length of the result is the length of the first argument. It is better to use the `%in%` syntax to prevent such a confusion: `key[key$num %in% samp,]`. Also note that you can reset the row names easily just by assigning NULL, no need for explicit sequence creation.

Comment: @Tomas: The OP wanted a result the length of `samp`. `match(key$num, samp)` produces several `NA` and `key[key$num %in% samp,]` is missing one row and is in the wrong order. I agree with your `rownames<-` comment.

Comment: Joshua, I must admit I had not enough energy to understand the particular situation of the OP. What makes me confused is that `match(samp, key$num)` is TRUE/FALSE vector will of length of `samp` instead of length of `key`, which is a bit weird when you use it for subsetting the `key`, or at least unusual. If this works then only in this particular situation...

Answer (score 3):

`join` in the `plyr` package is great for this...

```
samp <- c(9, 1, 4, 1)
num <- 1:10
vol <- sample(50:100, 10)
key <- data.frame(num, vol)
samp<-as.data.frame(samp)
names(samp)<-"num"
library("plyr")
join(key,samp,type="right")
```